# Is the address returned by operator(&) virtual?

Tags: c++, memory-address, virtual-memory

If yes, then why subsequent invocations of the same program results in different addresses, which vary greatly?

Here is result of the program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int i;

    cout<<&i;

    return 0;
}
```

-

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:0

0xbf8a5fac

Success time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:0

0xbfa71c8c

Success time: 0 memory: 3456 signal:0

0xbf8c55ac

Success time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:0

0xbf9aea4c

Success time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:0

0xbffddb1c
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the address operator is not virtual: it doesn't make sense to call it virtual.

What you see is that your program's machine stack is placed at different addresses each time you run the program, called [ASLR, *Address Space Layout Randomization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). That's a typical randomization to help defeat malware that relies on fixed known addresses. It has nothing to do with the language, but rather with the build tools.

With Visual C++ the randomization feature can be turned off, but it's generally not advisable to do that.

---

It can make at least associative sense to say that the *address* is virtual, but this has nothing to do with the result you're seeing. Virtual memory relies on a hardware level indirection for addresses, so that each *logical address* used by a process is translated on-the-fly to a corresponding *physical address*, which allows e.g. swapping pages of memory to disk. On the PC there is an intermediate layer, i.e. two levels of indirection, and the common terminology does not really cover this.

---

Note that for class types the basic address operator can be overridden.

One way to ensure that the built-in address operator is used is then to cast the lvalue expression to refence to `char` before applying the address operator, and essentially that's what [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) does.

Comment: I think the author meant whether an address is virtual or physical, not whether operator& is virtual. The address is definitely virtual.

Comment: @AlexStepanov: Yes possibly. Thanks. I added a paragraph about that.